How do I change the number of columns and rows in the terminal?
I have been developing a graphic library for generating 2d graphics on the terminal. I need to control the number of rows and columns to specify the resolution.

AFAIK it's usually done the other way around - programs read the current window size and format their output accordingly. See for example How are terminal information (such as window size) sent to a Linux program?.

To change the number of rows and columns in terminal open Terminal and select the hamburger menu ≡ after which select Preferences then profile Unnamed.

Change the values in Text Appearance to suit your requirements. Close the window and terminal et voila! Next time you open terminal, by default you will have the settings you require.
